# Can Azure Active Directory be used for complete User Management from Backend(NodeJS)

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, amazon-cognito, auth0

I have been able to set up Azure AD Authentication with Auth0. According to my research, Azure AD is similar to AWS Cognito and Firebase. So can we use Azure AD to handle flows like User Creation, Password Reset, Expire Password etc. from a NodeJS Admin Backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Ad is microsoft's identity platform. while yes in some ways is similar to aws cognito, it is a bit different as well. it's not designed specifically for developers, it's designed as an identity platform for your organization.

to answer your second question, it really depends on what you are expecting it to do. For example, there is an api, called graph api, which lets you interact and do almost everything you want to azure ad through that api. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api create users, groups etcetc. but if you are looking for user signup using their own emails and that sort of thing, the closest thing you should be looking at is Azure Ad B2C.
Azure B2c Takes care of some of the more common scenarios like signups and such
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/external-identities/b2c/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Graph API fits my requirement.